# Fetching variable values in C

Tags: c, string

I've been struggling with a code bit that outputs string content after it is split into a smaller substring.

The part where the string is split works more or less as expected. What I am struggling with, is capturing the array contents when it is returned from the `split` function.

See mock code that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **split(const char *string, const char *delimiter)
{
    printf("String length %zu\n", strlen(string));
    char *params[strlen(string)];
    char input[strlen(string)];

    strcpy(input, string);

    int i = 0;

    params[i] = strtok(input, delimiter);
    printf("Chunk %d = %s\n", i, params[i]);

    while(params[i] != NULL) {

        char *chunk = strtok(NULL, delimiter);

        params[++i] = chunk;

        printf("Chunk %d = %s\n", i, params[i]);
    }

    size_t size = sizeof(char **) * (i + 1);

    printf("Size %zu\n", size);

    char **destination = malloc(size);
    memcpy(destination, params, size);

    printf("First element %s\n", *destination);

    return destination;
}

char **function() 
{
  return split("this is a test", " ");
}

void read(char **elements) 
{
  printf("First element %s\n", *elements);

  char *b = *elements;

  printf("First element %s\n", b);
}

int main(void) 
{  
  char **elements = function();

  printf("First element %s\n", *elements);

  read(elements);

  printf("First element %s\n", *elements);

  return 0;
}
```

The following code outputs:

```
String length 14
Chunk 0 = this
Chunk 1 = is
Chunk 2 = a
Chunk 3 = test
Chunk 4 = (null)
Size 40
First element this
First element ��]�
First element �]�
First element �]�
First element ��]�
```

The first occurence of `First element` is succeeded by the `this` string, which is as expected. Although I'm not able to properly output the contents of first element outside the `split` function.

What am I doing wrong? A little suggestion that would point to the source of the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you debugged it?

Comment: @t0mm13b I've tried debugging it with DDD on Linux. It was crashing all the time, so I couldn't really debug the program properly. I'm going to try once more in X Code.

Comment: `char input[strlen(string)]; strcpy(input, string);` out of bounds write.

Comment: @EOF Do you think that is the root cause? If you look closely the chunks are printed out correctly in the `split` function. My question is focused on the variable output in `main`, `read` and `function` functions. I suspect I'm using pointers in a wrong way.

Comment: @dummy: I'm not searching for "the root cause" in a program that exhibits undefined behavior. It's allowed to do whatever it wants.

Comment: @EOF You were right about the out-of-bounds write.

Comment: @EOF, could you post that as an answer so the OP can accept it?

Comment: the `read()` is a well known system function, brought into scope via the #include <stdio.h> statement.   it is poor programming practice to name a user function the same as a system function, especially when that system function declaration is available to the program/compiler